# How to switch to Firefox 64 bit on Ubuntu 16.04.01 32 bit?

Tags: firefox, 64-bit, 32-bit

Currently I have Ubuntu 16.04.10 32 bit and Firefox Quantum 57.0.4 (32-bit). When I open some websites, they show that browser is critically out of date. I tried to update/install Firefox via command line but the version remains the same. How to run the newest browser on Ubuntu 16.04.10 32 bit? Is Firefox 32bit still supported or should switch to 64bit?

Output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://ubuntu-archive.mirror.serveriai.lt/ xenial restricted universe main multiverse
deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/ stable non-free
# deb-src [arch=amd64,i386] https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/ stable non-free
```

Output of `lsb_release -a`:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Comment: What is the output of `lsb_release -a; cat /etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: Updated the post.

Comment: You should reset repository list, as it doesn't work. https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories

Answer (score 0):

Your Ubuntu is running 16.04.3 which was released way back in August '17 while the latest point release is 16.04.6 released in February '19. Also, it seems that your Ubuntu's repository information is also outdated due to which you can't update Firefox. To update repository information, run:

```
sudo apt update
```

Then to update Firefox:

```
sudo apt upgrade firefox
```

To upgrade the system to 16.04.6:

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks but it shows the same Firefox version after executing these commands.

Comment: @Justas Try changing the server from Software and updates app.

Comment: Tried, shows that is already up to date and the same old version.

Comment: @Justas What is the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` now?

Comment: It worked after resetting repository list as it is mentioned the comment below question.

Comment: @Justas Glad you have solved it. Actually I wasn't sure about the current mirrors and repositories you were using. If you found this answer helpful you can mark it as accepted or if you have done something totally different you can write your own answer. Thanks :)